# change edges line color when the connected node clicked in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, networking, graph, cytoscape.js

could someone give an example of Cytoscape.js about a node that when it clicked, the neighbors edges changed its styles.

this code doesn't work:

```js
cy.$('node:selected').neighborhood('edge').style({
  'line-color': 'black'
});
cy.$('node:selected').connectedEdges().style({
  'line-color': 'black'
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
cy.$('node').on('grab', function (e) {
    var ele = e.target;
    ele.connectedEdges().style({ 'line-color': 'red' });
});


cy.$('node').on('free', function (e) {
    var ele = e.target;
    ele.connectedEdges().style({ 'line-color': '#FAFAFA' });
});
```

Comment: As I have a lot of information on the screen, sometimes it is difficult for the user to see all the node connections, so when selecting a node and / or drag, I change the colors of all the lines in red so that the user can achieve view all connections of that selected node.

Comment: when I release the element I return with the desired color in the event (free)

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition by assuming the order of events of tap/click and select.

Use `:selected` selectors for querying only with `select` events or use `tap` with the element passed in the event object.